# Jquery ajax posting to mvc controller parameter value is null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Try to post to a controller using ajax, successfully posting, but the parameter value is always null.

I am only posting the FromDate and ToDate viewmodel values to the controller.

Here is my ajax code:

```
var membersGenerateReportForm = $('#MembersGenerateReportForm').serialize();

$("#MembersGenerateBtn").click(function () {
        if ($("#MembersGenerateReportForm").valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                xhr: createXHR,
                url: '@Url.Action("MembersReport", "Report")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: membersGenerateReportForm,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("data: " + data.message);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("data: " + data.message);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

my html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MembersReport", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MembersGenerateReportForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <section class="row-fluid">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h4>
                        Generate member registrations report
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <h5>From Date</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "input-block-level", placeholder = "From Date" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromDate)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <h5>To Date</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new {@class = "input-block-level", placeholder = "To Date"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ToDate)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <h5>Action</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <div class="controls controls-row">
                                <input id="MembersGenerateBtn" value="Generate Report" class="btn btn-blue" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
}
```

No matter what value I put inside the datepicker fields, the value always becomes 01/01/0001, not sure what I'm doing wrong, the controller is not completed yet, as I'm still trying to figure out how to return File using Ajax call.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

**UPDATE**

My view model as requested:

```
public class MembersReportViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = @"From Date")]
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = @"To Date")]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show your model. And the culture on the server one that expects dates in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: If you are specifying date format on UI, then your culture should be having  the same date format, otherwise it won't resolve it. Suppose you have eb-GB then date format would dd/MM/yy and system will automatically cast that string into date but if you have en-GB format and you pass a date in MM/dd/yy format then it would not be able to understand date and will provide either exception or wrong results.

Comment: I don't think the problem is the format, i've tried using just strings, and it is giving me null value

Comment: Your values will be bound fine assuming you pass back a date in the format expected by the serer culture.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've tried using simple strings instead of date, and the string passed is null.

Comment: If you enter `2016-04-21` in the textbox (i.e. ISO format) is the value bound?

Comment: Nop still not bound, is it because of the way I serialized my form? Do i have to de-serialize it first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109756/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-eric-wang).